# The loop is only looping Once, please help find solution C#, MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, loops

I am trying to execute mysql query inside a loop where it get new results every time. The problem I am facing is that, the loop is looping successfully only for the first time, second time it says.That means if it has the idcount as 5 it only goes to 1 and when it enters 2 the error appears.

**Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read ()**
it is on this line "*string result2 = mysqlReader5[0].ToString();*"

It would be nice of you if you can help me to make this a successful loop

Thanx in Advance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < idcount; i++)
    {
        connection.Open();

        string x = idarray[i];


        ImageLoop img = new ImageLoop();
        image[i] =img.imageloop(x);

        MySqlCommand mysqlCmd5 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT  image  FROM useralbum where user_id='" + x + "' LIMIT 0,1;", connection);

        MySqlDataReader mysqlReader5 = mysqlCmd5.ExecuteReader();

        while (mysqlReader5.Read())
        {

        }
        string result2 = mysqlReader5[0].ToString();


        image[i] = result2;

        connection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the reader outside the while loop, it should be inside. Like:

```
while (mysqlReader5.Read())
    {
    string result2 = mysqlReader5[0].ToString();
    image[i] = result2;
    }
```

Also the assignment to `image[i]` should be done inside the while loop.

Comment: But then why did it worked for the first loop and not for the others.

Comment: @Amalan, how can you say that, you get the exception as soon as you get to the line `string result2 = mysqlReader5[0].ToString();` in the first iteration of for loop

Comment: this is for a web service the error indicated the problem in this line.Also when I added the break point and checked the array's first value is retrieved from the database. 
this is the line that indicated it "in c:\Users\Amalan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Amalan\App_Code\ArrayDetails.cs:line 156"

Comment: Hey Buddy you are right, your answer solved the problem.
Thank You Very Much...!

Answer (score 1):

You should be accessing the value inside the while block

```
while (mysqlReader5.Read())
{
// this block is getting executed while there are records
}
string result2 = mysqlReader5[0].ToString();
```

Also it would better if you could use [`Using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) blocks and shift the for loop inside, so that you avoid the opening and close of the connection each time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using while, first check the value of `mysqlReader5.Read()`

```
if (mysqlReader5.Read())
{
   string result2 = mysqlReader5[0].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your implementation....try this link for reference

http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04

datareader[0] returns the first column value.it is not used to access the array of results (Use data table for that).And data reader does not return an array of results and it only fetch one result at a time.So u need to read each data inside the while (mysqlReader5.Read()).I hope it helps!!!!